# Create Recurring profiled failed in sandbox

Tags: api, paypal

I have working on SANDBOX. I am getting error :

[0] => Array
                (
                    [L_ERRORCODE] => 11502
                    [L_SHORTMESSAGE] => Invalid Token
                    [L_LONGMESSAGE] => The token is invalid
                    [L_SEVERITYCODE] => Error
                )

This is what i passing in CreateRecurringProfile :

[REQUESTDATA] => Array
        (
            [USER] => "API_USER"
            [PWD] => "API_PASS"
            [VERSION] => 74.0
            [BUTTONSOURCE] => AngellEYE_PHPClass
            [SIGNATURE] => "API_SING"
            [METHOD] => CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile
            [TOKEN] => EC-8F723718H3002730R
            [SUBSCRIBERNAME] => Tester Testerson
            [PROFILESTARTDATE] => 2012-09-06T00:00:00\Z
            [DESC] => Item 1 Name
            [AUTOBILLAMT] => 1
            [BILLINGPERIOD] => Month
            [BILLINGFREQUENCY] => 1
            [TOTALBILLINGCYCLES] => 0
            [AMT] => 10.00
            [CURRENCYCODE] => USD
            [EMAIL] => hide@address.com
            [BUSINESS] => Testers, LLC
            [FIRSTNAME] => Tester
            [LASTNAME] => Testerson
        )

NOTE: I have removed SANDBOX API Credential. To show here.

Please give me solution what is missing here or what is fault in my posting request.

Thanks for advance

Answer (score 0):

Did you include L_BILLINGTYPE0=RecurringPayments in your SetExpressCheckout and DoExpressCheckoutPayment API calls?

Comment: Nope.. i didnot add that but after adding this, same error :(